# Aerospike - Data in RAM capacity planning

Tags: aerospike

I was using [this](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity) page for capacity planning but I feel an ambiguity there:

The very first section "Data Storage Required" tells in the last paragraph - "Data can be stored in RAM or on flash storage (SSD)". Does it mean that above calculations are relevant for both RAM and SSD?

Cause lower - another section exists called "For Data" and it states that "If a namespace is configured to store data in memory, the RAM requirement can be calculated as the sum of:" - and provides different numbers comparing to the first section.

Assuming that I want to keep all my data in RAM - which section is relevant to me? Could anyone suggest?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of data will you be storing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aerospike is a database that has very flexible [storage options](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/index.html) for its [namespaces](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html). Each namespace defines its own storage.

For data stored in memory you have two options:

- [In-memory without persistence](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/index.html#recipe-for-data-in-memory-without-persistence) (essentially a Redis-like cache, but on a distributed data store)
- [In-memory with persistence](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/namespace/storage/index.html#recipe-for-a-hdd-storage-engine-with-data-in-memory) to either a file or a [raw device](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#device).

To do capacity planning for the first case (in-memory no persistence) you would look at the [index memory required](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity#memory-required) - 64B per-object if you're not using the optional secondary indexes. To that you'd add the [in-memory storage cost](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity#for-data).  Mind you, if you declared the namespace to be [`single-bin`](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#single-bin) too, it would [save](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity#for-data-in-single-bin-namespaces-) some of the overhead.

If you're using persistence, memory is same as above, and the SSD/filesystem storage cost is calculated using the [Data Storage Required](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity#data-storage-required) section up top (as is the case for data-on-SSD).